# Rotate node to look at another node

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

Cocos Creator - I have a node that I want to rotate towards another node, here is the code I'm using:

```
update: function (dt) {
    this.rotate();
},

rotate: function () {
    var diff =  this.target.position - this.node.position;
    var angle = Math.atan2(diff.x, diff.y);
    this.node.rotation = cc.radiansToDegress(angle);
},
```

But it's not rotating at all, I tried to search the [docs](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/editors_and_tools/creator/index.html) but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var diff =  this.target.position - this.node.position;
```

You're basically trying to subtract an object from an object. Check

```
{'x':2, 'y':3} - {'x':4, 'y':6}
```

in your JS console. The result is `NaN`
You need to subtract each dimension manually.

```
var diff = {
'x' : this.target.position.x - this.node.position.x,
'y':this.target.position.y - this.node.position.y 
};
```

Comment: It works now, but something wrong with the angle, it's not giving the desired behaviour.

Comment: Math,atan2 accepts angle measured in radians. Cocos measures rotation in degrees. That's your problem

Comment: But I'm already converting radians to degrees, what am I missing here?!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to necro this question, but since this is a top search result I just wanted to add that the problem here is that the signature of `Math.atan2` takes it's coordinates backwards:

**Syntax:**

```
Math.atan2(y, x)
```

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2